# Нужно ли блочить поток при чтении в C++?

Tags: c++

Нужно ли блочить поток мютексом или семафором при чтении из другого потока?

Comment: Нужно блочить, иначе можно прочесть не то что на самом деле там содержится (мусор). В отдельных случаях (InterlockedExchange) можно не блочить и данные не испортятся.

Comment: Если данные может изменять какой-то другой поток, то да.

Comment: Что такое "чтение из другого потока"? Чтение *чего*? О чем речь вообще?

Comment: С с++17 для этих целей есть [shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/shared_mutex). Множество потоков могут читать один и те же данные одновременно, но при появлении желающего записать все "читатели" будут ждать пока "писатель" не закончит

Answer (score 0):

Семафоров в языке С++ нет (в стандартной библиотеке). Для чтения и записи данных из переменных, которые могут использоваться разными потоками нужно либо использовать `std::mutex` либо (если тип позволяет) `std::atomic`, иначе никакое поведение вашей программы не гарантированно.